# ASP.NET MVC on 2008 R2 IIS7.5 Not Loading

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

as the title notes, we can't get in to our site.

this same site works fine for us in 2003 and in our dev environments.  but once we moved to 2008 R2: we "can't get in".

i'd love it if we could use fuslogvw to watch the assembly bindings: but that's not possible on these servers (no sdk installed).

i've seen other posts that say nothing special is required for iis7 or 7.5, but we've got to be missing something...

we do get an expception:

*Unable to resolve controller of type: OurController.HomeController
StructureMap.StructureMapException StructureMap Exception Code 207: 
Internal exception while creating Instance*

error 207 is defined as : Internal exception in the constructor function of the targeted concrete type. InstanceKey "{0}", PluginFamily

any suggestions?

Comment: your error has to do with how StructureMap is constructing your controller. Does the constructor of your controller do anything with session state, or HttpContext? Do you have a machine with IIS 7 on it that you can build and debug the application? The development environment and deployment environment should really match. See if you can get a virtual machine with Vista, or Win 7, or Server 2008 on it with VS so you can build and debug.

Comment: Are the boxes running 3.5 sp1 (I think, whatever is current)? Have you installed the ASP.NET MVC runtime bits?

Answer (score 4):

make sure that both of these entries are in your `<system.webserver>` section in yoru web.config. The handler is something that is required for IIS 7+ but not lesser versions.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
       type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule,
             System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0,
             Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <add name="UrlRoutingHandler"
       preCondition="integratedMode"
       verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd"
       type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, 
             System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
             PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: yeah: this is one of the first things i verified... :(  

i added the exception we get to the question...

Comment: Have been cracking head for hours, finally got the right stuff, thnx mate :)

Answer (score 1):

We resolved this issue.

We were overwriting the default authentication and we needed to declare the assemblies down in the `system.webServer` section that nerdfury mentioned.